# Whitespace gap in page and CSS does not include element.style

Tags: html, css

I have strange whitespace in my login page:

```
http://buy.sd/index.php?route=account/login
```

When I inspect the code, I get the following:

```
element.style {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: url(http://buy.sd/undefined) no-repeat;
```

If I adjust the height to 10px it fixes the issue I'm having, but the element.style lines are not in my CSS files at all. Can you please advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see that is a `div` element with no content in it. Is it possible you could disable it from a backside configuration?

Alternatively, as a quick fix, you could hide the `div` with `display: none;` as follows:

```
#slideshow0{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but that's not a good solution at all. Using `!important` should be avoided at all times and this is not a nice approach to the problem. @XavierOjeda

Comment: I agree with you, I just used it as a quick fix to the problem. I edited the answer mentioning that. Thank you!

Comment: That's fair. No worries. I'd just add that the roules are basically added trough `JavaScript`, just in case he wants to modify the roule directly. Thanks! @XavierOjeda

Answer (score 0):

These `CSS rules` are added trought `JavaScript` or `jQuery` scripts. Please check your scripts to remove or edit this `CSS inline` roules.